# How Fetch Emails From A Specific Email Address On My Mail Server With C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, fetch, mail-server

i created a mail server for myself using hmail + roundcube + windows server 2008 - r2 installed on a vps!
every thing is ok about them and now i want to fetch emails from a specific email address created in hmail!
how can i read all those inbox emails?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an IMAP library similar to this one featured in this post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8008/IMAP-Client-library-using-C. Using IMAP your code will simply login to your server, in a similar fashion to a mail client and be able to access the mail box and mail. This specific library will allow you to return the mail message as an XML payload for you to process.

Comment: thanks for the answer man, would you please give me some info about user and pass? mean in roundcube login i enter username (main@mydomain.com) and pass(pass of email, set in hmail) and server (mydomain.com) | now i want to test that library | but i could n't login by upper info | should i set imap username and password somewhere or those username and password are for that specific email | also which port should i use? (143 or 993)? should i change something in hmail and roundcube configs?